# How can I modify this bash script so that the port argument is optional?

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, bash-scripting

I often connect through ssh to Docker containers running on a remote server. Every time the container is stopped or removed, I need to copy my ssh key on the container again, in order to connect. For this reason, on my Mac laptop I put this simple bash script, whose goal is simply to add my ssh key to the Docker container to which I want to connect.

```
#!/bin/bash

# A POSIX variable
OPTIND=1         # Reset in case getopts has been used previously in the shell.

# Default parameter value:
PORT=...
PUBKEY=...
HOST_IP=...

# show_help function
show_help() {
    echo "Usage: $(basename "$0") [-h] [-p PORT] [-f PUBKEY] [-i HOST_IP]"
    echo
    echo "   -p PORT           add key to container running on port PORT (default: ...)"
    echo "   -f PUBKEY         add key file PUBKEY (default: ...)"
    echo "   -i HOST_IP        connect to host HOST_IP (default: ...)"
    echo
    return
}


while getopts ":h:p:f:i:" option; do
  case "$option" in
    \?)
      echo "invalid argument"
      show_help
      exit 1
      ;;
    h)
      show_help
      exit 0
      ;;
    p)  PORT=$OPTARG
      ;;
    f)  PUBKEY=$OPTARG
      ;;
    i)  HOST_IP=$OPTARG
      ;;
  esac
done

shift $((OPTIND-1))

USER_AT_HOST="root@$HOST_IP"
PUBKEYPATH="$HOME/.ssh/$PUBKEY"
ssh-copy-id -i "$PUBKEYPATH" "$USER_AT_HOST" -p "$PORT"

exit 0
```

I have two problems:

1. (smaller) the arguments have non-intuitive letters (`f` for the `PUBKEY`, `i` for the `HOST_IP`) because if I'm not mistaken, `getopts` only support single-letter arguments. Is there any way to circumvent this limitation? If not, could you suggest some more creative/self-explanatory letters for the arguments?
2. (bigger) currently the `-p` argument (`PORT`) is mandatory, and the user used for the ssh connection is always `root`. I would like to modify the script so that, if the `-p` argument is not passed, then another argument `-u` (`USER`) must be passed, and the connection command becomes

   ```
    USER_AT_HOST="$USER@$HOST_IP"
    PUBKEYPATH="$HOME/.ssh/$PUBKEY"
    ssh-copy-id -i "$PUBKEYPATH" "$USER_AT_HOST"
   ```

   instead than

   ```
    USER_AT_HOST="root@$HOST_IP"
    PUBKEYPATH="$HOME/.ssh/$PUBKEY"
    ssh-copy-id -i "$PUBKEYPATH" "$USER_AT_HOST" -p "$PORT"
   ```

How could I modify the script in order to obtain this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this implementation, you don't specify default values up front.

The arguments to `ssh-copy-id` are built up in an array. Note the use of `+=` to *append* to the array.

Other notes:

- `OPTIND=1` is only needed if you `source` this script. If you're running
  it as a script, then the variable is unset before you get to `getopts`
- I'd remove `exit 0` at the bottom of the script: let it exit with
  `ssh-copy-id`'s exit status.
- Your code forgot `i` in the opt string for getopts. Double check this.
- `?*` is a shell pattern (aka "wildcard") that matches at least 1 character.
- Get out of the habit of using ALLCAPS variable names, leave those as
  reserved by the shell. One day you'll write `PATH=something` and then
  [wonder why](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27555060/7552)
  your [script is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28310594/7552).
- an alternate way to set a default value is to use the `:` command

  ```bsh
  : ${var:="default value"}
  ```

  But that's a bit opaque.

---

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# show_help function
show_help() {
    echo "Usage: $(basename "$0") [-h] [-p PORT|-u] [-f PUBKEY] [-i HOST_IP]"
    echo
    echo "   -p PORT           add key to container running on port PORT (default: ...)"
    echo "   -u USER           help string here..."
    echo "   -f PUBKEY         add key file PUBKEY (default: ...)"
    echo "   -i HOST_IP        connect to host HOST_IP (default: ...)"
    echo
    return
}

while getopts ":hi:p:f:u:" option; do
  case "$option" in
    p)  port=$OPTARG ;;
    f)  pubkey=$OPTARG ;;
    i)  host_ip=$OPTARG ;;
    u)  user=$OPTARG ;;
    h)  show_help; exit 0 ;;
    ?)  echo "invalid argument"; show_help; exit 1 ;;
  esac
done

shift $((OPTIND-1))     # not needed if there are no positional parameters

[[ -z $host_ip ]] && host_ip="default value"
[[ -z $pubkey ]] && pubkey="default value"

cmd_args=( -i "$HOME/.ssh/$pubkey" )

case "$port,$user" in
    ,)  # empty port and empty user
        echo "If you don't specify a port, you need to specify a user" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
    ,?*) # empty port but user is specified
        cmd_args+=( "$user@$host_ip" )
        ;;
    ?*,*) # port has been given. user doesn't matter
        cmd_args+=( -p "$port" "root@$host_ip" )
        ;;
esac

ssh-copy-id "${cmd_args[@]}"
```

---

To address your comments:

- only options that take an argument use a colon. To demonstrate

  With a colon,

  ```bsh
  $ set -- -h
  $ getopts :h: opt
  $ declare -p opt OPTARG OPTIND
  declare -- opt=":"
  declare -- OPTARG="h"
  declare -i OPTIND="2"
  ```

  As [the manual for `getopts`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-getopts) says:

  > If a required argument is not found [...] a colon (`:`) is placed in name and OPTARG is set to the option character found.

  Without a colon, option parsing proceeds as you expect

  ```bsh
  $ unset opt OPTARG OPTIND
  $ set -- -h
  $ getopts :h opt
  $ declare -p opt OPTARG OPTIND
  declare -- opt="h"
  declare -- OPTARG
  declare -- OPTIND="2"
  ```
- Regarding default values, do the option parsing *first*. Then, if the variables are *not set by options*, provide the default value.

  ```bsh
  [[ -z $host_ip ]] && host_ip="default value"
  ```

  This means: if the value of `host_ip` is empty (`-z`), set the value to a default value.

Comment: thanks for the answer! A few questions: `while getopts ":hi:p:f:u:"`. Shouldn't there be a `:` between `h` and `i`, i.e., `while getopts ":h:i:p:f:u:"`? Also, you say that `With this implementation, you don't specify default values up front.`. However, I find default values useful because I often use the script with the same parameters. Could you explain a bit more in detail why I can't use default parameters? Finally, could you please explain the meaning of these two lines `[[ -z $host_ip ]] && host_ip="default value"`  `[[ -z $pubkey ]] && pubkey="default value"`? Thanks again